how do i adjust vjust and h just, so that i can see the values in graph. They are moving out of the graph or overlapping eachother
# Plot actual vs predicted
gg <- ggplot(pred_results, aes(x = Actual, y = Predicted)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(title = "Test Set: Actual vs Predicted",
       x = "Actual (%)",
       y = "Predicted (%)") +
  theme_minimal()

# Add annotations for model metrics
gg <- gg +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, hjust = 0, vjust = 0,
           label = paste("Model R-squared:", round(best_model_results$model_r2, 2))) +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5,
           label = paste("Test R-squared:", round(best_model_results$test_r2, 2))) +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, hjust = 0.7, vjust = 0.7,
           label = paste("Correlation:", round(best_model_results$correlation, 2))) +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, hjust = 0.8, vjust = 0.8,
           label = paste("MSE:", round(best_model_results$MSE, 2))) +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, hjust = 1, vjust = 1,
           label = paste("Max Error:", round(best_model_results$max_error, 2)))


image is added here:  

I tried changing the number, but I was not able to adjust the position.

Please run dput(pred_results) and dput(best_model_results) and add the results to a new codeblock in your question. This will make it easier to help you.

The main issue is that you are putting all labels at the same position aka the lower right corner of the plot. Instead I would suggest to use just one annotate to add your model stats as one label by pasting them together and separated by a line break. Additionally note that I switched to geom="label" as it allows to add some padding around the label.
Using some fake example data:
library(ggplot2)

# Fake example data
best_model_results <- list(
  model_r2 = 1,
  test_r2 = 1,
  correlation = 1,
  MSE = 1,
  max_error = 1
)

pred_results <- mtcars[c("hp", "mpg")]
names(pred_results) <- c("Actual", "Predicted")

# Plot
gg <- ggplot(pred_results, aes(x = Actual, y = Predicted)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue", alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(
    title = "Test Set: Actual vs Predicted",
    x = "Actual (%)",
    y = "Predicted (%)"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() 

gg +
  annotate("label",
    x = Inf, y = -Inf, hjust = 1, vjust = 0,
    label = paste(
      paste("Model R-squared:", round(best_model_results$model_r2, 2)),
      paste("Test R-squared:", round(best_model_results$test_r2, 2)),
      paste("Correlation:", round(best_model_results$correlation, 2)),
      paste("MSE:", round(best_model_results$MSE, 2)),
      paste("Max Error:", round(best_model_results$max_error, 2)),
      sep = "\n"
    ),
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0
  )


